# How to override s3 data using Glue job in AWS using database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

How do I write overwrite the parquet file using database as below:

```
DataSink0 = glueContext.getSink(path = "s3://mybucket/", connection_type = "s3", updateBehavior = "LOG", partitionKeys = ["codigo"], enableUpdateCatalog = True, transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
DataSink0.setCatalogInfo(catalogDatabase = "database-gold",catalogTableName = "address")
DataSink0.setFormat("glueparquet")
DataSink0.writeFrame(Transform0)

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you currently **can not use overwrite** when using Glue's `DynamicFrame` API. You would need to convert that DynamicFrame to a Spark `DataFrame` and use the Spark API, like this:

```
data_frame.write.mode("overwrite").save("s3a://test_bucket/")
```